# php class constructor

Tags: php, class

Hi I have a class as follows:

```
<?php
include '(OrderContainer.php)';
class OrderAuthenticator
{
     private $OrderObj;
     public function __construct($Order)
    {
        $this->OrderObj = $Order;
         echo 'Created an instance os OrderContainer<br/>';
    }

    //Misc methods.....


}
?>
```

Then I have a method that tries to instantiate this object

```
<?php
include ('OrderAuthenticator.php');

$Authenticator = new OrderAuthenticator($OrderObj);

?>
```

Problem is that in the object is not instantiated.....
No matter what I do ..... Im new to PHP so I was wondering if there is something quite obvious here that Im not doing?

Could someone please give me a hand..
Thanks

Comment: `$OrderObj` is undefined.  Where is this coming from?

Comment: No I dont see any errors. $OrderObj is a a variable to hold an instance of $OrderContainer that is passed to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. $OrderObj is defined earlier in the code, I didn't bother to write the whole file. But, It is instantiated earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as `include '(OrderContainer.php)';` should be `include('OrderContainer.php');` instead.

Make sure `$OrderObj` is defined in the main script creating an instance of OrderAuthenticator.

To debug, be sure that PHP is showing error messages by starting with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` first in the main script.

Also, make sure you have no syntax error (for example, by printing "Hello world" in your script).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `$OrderObj` to be passed in to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Just remove public from constructor.

Comment: Why "Just remove public from constructor."?